# How to remove padding from FlowRow?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using Jetpack Compose FlowRow from `androidx.compose.foundation` compose version `1.0.0-alpha03`. I noticed there is a padding which I can't remove from my layout.

The ideia is similar to this image but I would like to remove all the paddings.

[image: FlowRow]

Here is my code, I'm trying to remove the text padding and also FlowRow padding:

```
FlowRow(
        crossAxisSpacing = 0.dp,
        mainAxisSpacing = 0.dp,
        mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.Start,
        mainAxisSize = SizeMode.Wrap
    ) {
        Text(text = "1", modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp))
        Text(text = "2", modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp))
        Text(text = "3", modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp))
        Text(text = "4", modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp))
        Text(text = "5", modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp))
        Text(text = "6", modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp))
        Text(text = "7", modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp))
        Text(text = "8", modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp))
        Text(text = "9", modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp))
   }
```

Comment: Try to update to latest version **1.0.0-alpha05**.

Answer (score 0):

As @Muthukrishnan Rajendran commented, updating the version will solve it.

It's important to notice that you could have figured out that it was a bug, since a quick look at the documentation shows us that the behavior you were trying to achieve is the default behavior, and Jetpack Compose is still alpha.

Here is the docs for reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#flowrow